# How to refer to an outer function from a lambda?

Tags: kotlin

The question is in the comment. I want to refer to the outer function `append`, and not the one that's defined in the `StringBuilder`, how do I do this?

```
fun append(c: Char) {
    println("TEST")
}

fun sbTest() = with(StringBuilder()) {
    for(c in 'A'..'Z') {
        append(c) // how do I refer to the append function declared above?
    }
    toString()
}
```

I know I can introduce a function reference variable, like this:

`val f = ::append`

and call `f` instead of `append`, but is there another way?

Comment: Is it inside a class?

Comment: @Zoe no, it's top-level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that anything called within `with` shadows the outer functions, because `this` is introduced. The same problem appears if you have a class and a top-level function with a function with the same signature.

The obvious option would just be re-naming it. Also, the function you have there isn't really descriptive compared to what it actually does. But if you for some reason can't rename, there are still other options.

Top-level methods can be referenced by package in Kotlin, for an instance like `com.some.package.method`. It can also be imported as such, which is the most common way to do it. There are very few methods that are called as `com.some.package.method()`.

Kotlin, like Python, allows `as` in imports. Which means, you can do this:

```
package com.example;

// This is the important line; it declares the import with a custom name.
import com.example.append as appendChar; // Just an example name; this could be anything ***except append***. If it's append, it defeats the purpose

fun append(c: Char) {
    println("TEST")
}

fun sbTest() = with(StringBuilder()) {
    for(c in 'A'..'Z') {
        appendChar(c) 
    }
    toString()
}
```

Alternatively, as I mentioned, you can add the package:

```
for(c in 'A'..'Z') {
    com.example.append(c) 
}
```

`val f = ::append` is of course an option too, either way, it is still easier to rename the function than create imports with `as` or constants, assuming you have access to the function (and that it doesn't belong to a dependency).

---

If your file is outside a package, which I do not recommend you do, you can just declare the import as:

```
import append as appendChar
```

Comment: what if it's not inside any package? no way to do it then?

Comment: You should always use packages though. I'll check

Comment: In the first sentence of your post, did you mean `with` instead of `when`?

Comment: @Coder-Man meant `with`, yeah. My bad ^^"

Answer (score 2):

You could also use an extension function instead of `with()`, such as `.let{...}`. 
This will send `StringBuilder` as an argument to the extension function as `it` (You can rename it to whatever you want btw):

```
fun sbTest() = StringBuilder().let{ it ->
    for(c in 'A'..'Z') {
        // using string builder
        it.append(c)
        // using your function
        append(c) 
    }
    it.toString()
}
```

The `.let{...}` function returns your last statement, aka the String from `toString()`, so your original function would still return it properly. Other functions can return `this` instead, such as `.also{...}`

I tend to use extension functions rather than `with()` as they're more flexible.

See this post to master extension functions: https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84

**EDIT:** Got `also{}` and `let{}` mixed up. I switched them